# User Specific Profile Page with CRUD functionality in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, crud

I'm a Django newbie and for the last few weeks, I've followed some foundational tutorials on app creation with user login, logout, and authentication functionality. In each tutorial, the CRUD functionality is enabled across all users but the content is aggregated on the application homepage. For example, in the blog creation tutorial, you can register a user, login to the application, and generate a blog post, however, the blog post is rendered on the application homepage where any user can view that content.

Can anyone point me towards a resource (docs or tutorial) that explains how to create an isolated content page for the user? Meaning, once the user registers, logs in and creates a blog post, it will only populate in the user's personal 'home' page and is not viewable (nor can it be edited) by the other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use django's generic display templates for this, e.g. `ListView`. And then you simply need to overwrite `get_queryset` like this:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.model.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

This will then return all the objects of only the logged in user.

Check out the documentation for more details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Answer (score 0):

in your view you can get the user from the request object

```
def user_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    user_posts = Posts.objects.filter(editor=user)
    return render(request, 'user_profile.html', {user_posts': user_posts})
```

on the template you can iterate the user_posts passed as context

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Use **Django Decorators** in every function which you want to make visible to a particular user. For example, If you want to make a dashboard page visible only to the logged-in user, do this

```
@login_required(login_url = "user:login")
def dashboard(request):
  articles = Article.objects.filter(author = request.user)
  context = {
    "articles":articles
}
return render(request,"dashboard.html",context)
```

In the above example we have used the folliwing decorator

```
@login_required(login_url = "user:login")
```